# Prove that every bijection of the set into itself is representable as a composition of two involutions.

Tags: set-theory, symmetry

**The task:** prove that every bijection of a set into itself is representable as a composition of two symmetries (on this set). There is no presumption on finiteness or infinity of the set.

**Proof (where I am at now and looking for insights):**

**1) Writing down the task into math language**

Let $f$ be bijection of the set $X$ into itself: $f: X\leftrightarrow X$.

Let $h$ be a symmetry on the set $X$ that means: $h: X\leftrightarrow X$ and $h^{-1} = h$.

Let $g$ be a symmetry on the set $X$ that means: $g: X\leftrightarrow X$ and $g^{-1} = g$.

**2) Need to prove that** $$\forall f:X\leftrightarrow X \exists (h:X\leftrightarrow X, h^{-1}=h \; and\; g:X\leftrightarrow X, g^{-1}=g):f= g\circ h.$$

**3) Proof**

Prove that there are $h$ and $g$ so that $f=g\circ h$.

Here is where I am getting into the problem.
While

1. I know that composition of two bijections is bijection.
2. I feel intuitively that every bijection can be represented as a composition of two bijections (by permutation in the middle - not sure that permutation thinking is valid for infinite sets).

I am struggling to get to the proof of that for every bijection $f:X\leftrightarrow X$ among many of the compositions of bijections $X\leftrightarrow X$ that equals $f$ - there are at least one composition that consists of two symmetries.

Comment: @JeanMarie why?

Comment: What you call "symmetries" are usually called involutions.

Comment: I can't find a duplicate of your question in one place. For the case of a finite set $X$ see [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3033171/find-f-g-s-t-f-circ-g-beginpmatrix1-2-3-4-5-6-7-8-9-10/3034786#3034786) or [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/497637/is-any-permutation-the-product-of-two-involutions).

Comment: For the case where $X$ is infinite and the permutation is just one infinite cycle, see [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2070222/does-having-a-finite-number-of-generators-each-having-finite-order-imply-that/2070228#2070228) (Example II) or [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/41303/examples-and-further-results-about-the-order-of-the-product-of-two-elements-in-a/2954762#2954762)..

Comment: @bof Thanks for the feedback. The theorem is the task from the book "ModernCalculus" by famous (in CIS) Boyarchuk, Golovach. This is the word by word translation.

Comment: @bof Thanks for the links - will check them and return.

Comment: It must be said that the sets under consideration are either finite or denumerable.

Comment: @JeanMarie I don't think that matters